# Why isn't Python fexlibe when it comes data-types of function arguments?

Tags: python, type-conversion

This is probably a bad title but what I mean by it is the following:

Since Python is dynamically-typed, why do certain functions *insist* on being used with certain data types only and do not handle the conversion themselves internally if necessary? What problems could that lead to?

**Examples:**

> `startswith()`: Takes both `str`ings and `tuple`s as arguments.

- Why not `list`s
  too? And if there is a good reason for that (which is probably the
  case), why does it not simply convert them internally?

> `join()`: Only accepts containers of `str`ing items.

- Why does it not simply do a `[str(x) for x in whatever]`?

From the design of the language, I have the impression so far that it values flexibility more than purity and therefore the above behavior seems kind of non-typical..

---

Another example comes from @VPfB

> "IPv4 address (host, port) must be tuple - not a list - in socket library.".

Can it be that tuples are prefered due to their immutability? Is there a case where a `tuple` is denied and only a `list` accepted? Preferably part from the standard Python distribution and its modules.

Comment: I'm not sure in the first case, but it the second case I'm almost certain is is done so as to prevent unintended side effects from going undetected... it is better for the programmer to know exactly what they're passing than the interpreter to make assumptions.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Could you provide an example for such an unintended side-effect?

Comment: Wait, tuples have a `startswith` method? Since when?

Comment: The often asked question "Why is a programming language like …." is not for stack overflow. Here you get help for programming questions. If you want to discuss the basic of Python, please ask the Python community at https://www.python.org/community/

Comment: @Rawing tuples do not have a `startswith` method but the string `startswith()` method can take a tuple as an argument to check against multiple strings. I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: @KlausD. Then think of the question as *"why can I not do* `'blabla'.startswith(['a', 'b'])` *but* `'blabla'.startswith(('a', 'b'))` *is fine?*"`

Comment: Another example: IPv4 address (host, port) must be tuple - not a list - in socket library.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Because `startswith` checks for a specific type. First it checks for `str`, otherwise it expects multiple strings. So it needs to check somehow for this and does it by checking for type `tuple`. It cannot just rely on the fact that the argument is an iterable and just apply `tuple(arg)` because there are many argument types for which this doesn't make sense (`bytes`, `bytestrings` for example for which the encoding is unknown). Surely it could check for `list` too but it's just a convention to use a `tuple` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> From the design of the language, I have the impression so far that it values flexibility more than purity and therefore the above behavior seems kind of non-typical.

Your impression is wrong. Python is dynamically-typed, but also strongly-typed, meaning that the type of an object is always fixed. If you need a different type of object, you have to compare it one way or the other.

The second question is legitimate, though – it would have been possible. But explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: _"Python is dynamically-typed, but also strongly-typed, meaning that the type of an object is always fixed."_ How come that the "type: of an object is always fixed and Python is polymorphic?

Answer (score 1):

Python is *strongly* dynamically typed which means that objects have definite types and conversions must be performed explicitly. For the why, consider the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.